# Why is the upper output 2 rather than 6 but the other one is 3?

Tags: bash, terminal, echo, dollar-sign

```
lab=(jeff roger brian)
lab[3]=sean
lab=("${lab[*]}" "${lab[*]}")
echo ${#lab[*]}
```

> echo $({lab[*]} > jeff roger brian sean jeff roger brian sean

> echo ${#lab[*]} > 2

> io=(io iu yu)

> echo ${io[*]} > io iu yu

> echo ${#io[*]} > 3

Comment: There are just two elements in the array; try `declare -p lab` to see that.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing the difference between `"${lab[*]}"` and `"${lab[@]}"`.

```
$ lab=(jeff roger brian)
$ lab2=("${lab[*]}" "${lab[@]}")
$ for x in "${lab2[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done
jeff roger brian
jeff
roger
brian
```

`"${lab[*]}"` is a single word consisting of all the elements in `lab` separated by a space.

`"${lab[@]}"` is a *sequence* of words, each word corresponding to a separate element of `lab`.

The definition of `lab2` above consists of *four* elements: a single word created from the contents of `lab`, and each of the three individual elements of `lab`.

If you fail to quote the expansion, as in `echo ${lab[*]}`, the distinction is somewhat lost, as the result is immediately subject to word-splitting, so that `echo` gets three separate arguments. Without quotes, `${lab[*]}` and `${lab[@]}` are essentially identical.